How can i get list of tokens inside wallet on Solana network?
I generated this code with Gemini but it doesnt work.
I want get list of tokens in wallet on Solana with their amount, what should i do?
I want python code.
import requests
from solana.rpc.api import Client
 
# Replace with your desired Solana node URL
SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

def get_wallet_tokens(wallet_address):

   client = Client(SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT)

   try:
       # Get token accounts associated with the wallet
       token_accounts = client.get_token_accounts_by_owner(wallet_address)
   except Exception as e:
       print(f"Error fetching token accounts for {wallet_address}: {e}")
       return []

   tokens = []
   for account in token_accounts['result']:
       try:
           # Get token metadata (optional) for name retrieval
           mint_address = account['info']['mint']
           metadata_url = f"https://api.devnet.solana.com/v1/tokens/{mint_address}/metadata"
           response = requests.get(metadata_url)
           metadata = response.json()
           token_name = metadata.get('name', '(Unknown)')  # Handle missing name
       except Exception as e:
           print(f"Error fetching metadata for {mint_address}: {e}")
           token_name = '(Unknown)'

       # Extract relevant information
       balance = account['info']['amount'] / 10**account['info']['token']['decimals']
       token_info = {'mint_address': mint_address, 'name': token_name, 'balance': balance}
       tokens.append(token_info)

   return tokens

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Example usage
   wallet_address = "AJuo8yxM9rFg9x767r3ArDCarUgBPe276K61zjfWuEcN"  # Replace with the wallet to track

   tokens = get_wallet_tokens(wallet_address)

   if tokens:
       print("Tokens in wallet:")
       for token in tokens:
           print(f"- {token['name']} ({token['mint_address']}): {token['balance']}")
   else:
       print("No tokens found in the wallet.")


I generated this code with Gemini but it doesnt work.
I want get list of tokens in wallet on Solana with their amount, what should i do?
